# Mocking Firebase as a dependency in Swift unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am currently trying to restructure my app to incorporate some UI tests, however a portion of the interface and model has a dependency on Firebase events. Is there an easy way (using some form of framework) to mock the Firebase objects and then use that framework to invoke the events?

Comment: When you say Firebase objects, do you mean Firebase, FDataSnapshot, FQuery?

Comment: The Firebase object itself in the context of attaching event listeners. The FDataSnapshots should be straight forward to mock but the event driven side is driving me a little crazy

Comment: Can you share a snippet on how you mock FDataSnapshots?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @AndrewBreen? I am trying to mock an authentication object

Comment: @Chris not cleanly no. What we ended up doing was creating "providers" that were providing the data to our VCs, then was able to mock those in the tests. Problem with that was the providers couldn't then be tested but at least we could do proper testing on the VCs.